# Event handler query at time that event is registered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I know certain queries take a bit longer than others (e.g., compound queries are slower than simple queries, ids are faster than classes, etc.). In my case, that's of practical significance. Wonder how it applies to queries in event handlers.

Does the query have any impact on the speed at which the event handler will fire? Or is the query already resolved to some sort of pointer to that object in the DOM?

For example, would these handlers be absolutely equivalent? :

```
$("body > section > #id div.class element").click(func);
$("#element").click(func);
```

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I believe the impact, although extremely small, would be seen when initially binding the event handler, not when firing it. It is my understanding that jQuery caches the DOM objects with the attached handlers internally for fast access. Not sure if this is true though. Maybe someone else could elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you give, the speed of the selector would only affect the initial setup of the page -- the speed to find the element on which to place the event handler.  Once the event handler is attached, the selector shouldn't affect the speed of the actual event handler firing.

The case in which selector speed could matter to an event handler would be where you use the `on()` function to define event handlers for elements that might not yet exist -- "delegated" events.  For example:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", func);
```

versus

```
 $( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", ".my-table-row", func);
```

The performance of the first event handler will be better (though it's absolutely worth pointing out that the difference is typically small).  The reason this case is different from your example is that the actual click handler is being placed on the `tbody`, and the selector is then used at fire time to determine whether a given event is a match.